# Why does my Reverse polish notation output the wrong output

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char input;
int X;
int buffer[16];
int i = 0;
int y = 0;
int tmp;
int tmp_va;
int output = 0;
int power[5] = {10000,1000,100,10,0};


int main()
{
  L1:
    input = getchar();



if(input == 0x0A){
  putchar(0x0A);

    if(buffer[i] > 0){
      i++;

    }
    buffer[i] = X;

  tmp = 0;
  }



      else if(input == 0x2B){
        putchar(0x2B);
        putchar(0x0A);
        X = buffer[i] + X;
        buffer[i] = 0;


        tmp = X;
        y = 0;
          L2:
            output = 0;

                tmp = tmp - power[y];
                output++;
                L3:
              if(tmp >= power[y]){
                goto L3;
              }
             if(tmp < X){
               output = output + 0x30;
               putchar(output);
             }
             y++;
          if(power[y] > 0){
            goto L2;
          }


         if(tmp >= 0){
          tmp = tmp + 0x30;
          putchar(tmp);
        }

        tmp = 0;


        if(i > 0){
          i--;
        }
     }

      else{
        putchar(input);
        if(tmp == 0){
          X = input - 0x30;
        }
        else{
          tmp_va = X;
          X = X << 3;
          tmp_va = tmp_va << 1;
          X = X + tmp_va;
          X = X + input - 0x30;
        }
        tmp = 1;
      }if (input != EOF){
        goto L1;
    }

    }
```

and it does what its supposed to do, which is that it should add numbers in reverse polish notation. However when I input an equation, it always outputs

```
111
```

instead of the correct answer. That it outputs the input again is deliberate.

Btw, I know, that it has goto loops, which is a requirement. I would appreciate any help enormously

The way it should work is:
you enter for example

you input: `3`
it outputs `3`
you enter `4+`
it outputs `4+`
it outputs `7`
what it does:

you input: `3`
it outputs `3`
you enter `4+`
it outputs `4+`
it outputs `1111`

so it looks likes this
3
3
4+
4+
7

but it does this
3
3
4+
4+
1111

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal

Comment: Have you debugged the program line by line to see how it works? What is the input given and what should be the output? You use arrays without initializing them etc so there are several things that could go wrong here.

Comment: Why are you using `goto` - I though we ditched that in the '90s

Comment: `int power[5] = {10000,1000,100,10,0};` -> `int power[] = {10000,1000,100,10,0};` - get the compiler to do the work

Comment: .. and please sort out the indentation

Comment: What is `0x2B` ?

Comment: And why so many global variables?

Comment: Please [read about loops](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html). While you may use `goto` for some things (e.g. break out of a loop inside a `switch` statement), it is not needed in your code as written above as much as you might think, if at all. A `goto` statement in any programming language is considered harmful and should be avoided if concepts such as loops exist in a language, and if a way to avoid `goto` exists. For example, the C programming language has the `break` and `continue` statements to jump out of a loop and to the end of a loop respectively.

Comment: Your code is a total mess: harcoded values, spaghetti control flow, bad indentation. You also didn't provide us the way it should work (examples of inputs, etc). Please clean it and you will probably see the problem by yourself, if not, you will be welcome back.

Comment: don't use magic numbers like `input == 0x0A`. Who knows what 0x0A is? It doesn't even have to be consistent across systems. Use `input == '\n'` instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be this

```
char input;
```

Note that `getchar` returns an `int` and you may have problems with `EOF` or values > `127`

Try

```
int input;
```

Comment: I did that and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Ok, anyway you need to fix this, notice that those magic numbers instead of character literals and the use of `goto`'s doesn't help to understand the code, please, clean that mess up ;)

Comment: I have code without goto here which works: https://pastebin.com/d1ekssXT however I have to get rid of all do/while and while loops

Comment: Why do you have to get rid of the while ... loops?

Comment: because, I have to then get rid of get rid of arrays and then translate to assembly and it's a requirement

Comment: If you need to write this assembly (why?) then write it in assembly in the first place

Comment: It's a requirement to submit a c file without while and do/while loops

Comment: @Servus If that's your version that works, then you misplaced the `L3` line label in your `goto` version in your question: it should be moved up 2 lines, atop `tmp = tmp - power[y];`

Comment: I did that what you suggested, but it still does the same

Answer (score 0):

After running through a debugger, it looks like your main problem, as far as the `1111` output is concerned, is this section where you add things and output the result:

```
int power[5] = {10000, 1000, 100, 10, 0};

/* skipping code */

tmp = X;
y = 0;
 L2: 
    output = 0;
    /* moved L3 from question's code to avoid loop issue */
     L3:
        tmp = tmp - power[y];
        output++;
        if (tmp >= power[y]) {
            goto L3;
        }
    if (tmp < X) {
        output = output + 0x30;
        putchar(output);
    }
    y++;
    if (power[y] > 0) {
        goto L2;
    }
if (tmp >= 0) {
    tmp = tmp + 0x30;
    putchar(tmp);
}
```

Let's suppose you enter 4, followed by a line feed (0x0A), followed by the `+` sign and another line feed (i.e. `4\n+\n`). (Aside: you don't set `X` back to 0 when you handle the line feed, resulting in `X==buffer[i]`, which might be a problem since that means `X = buffer[i] + X` is the same as `X = 2 * X` when you encounter a `'+'` on its own. I'm exploiting this bug to keep the explanation simpler since it doesn't affect the `1111` bug, but you should fix it.)

Bug setup (processing input):

1. `'4'` is not equal to `'\n'` (0x0A) and also not `'+'` (0x2B), so code flow proceeds to the `else` section.
2. `tmp==0` at this point, resulting in `X = input - 0x30`, or `X = 4`, followed by `tmp = 1`. The code flow jumps back to `L1`.
3. `'\n'` (0x0A) is detected, so code flow proceeds to the `if` section.
4. `i==0` at this point, and `buffer[i]==0` as well, so the `i++` is skipped.
5. `buffer[0] = X` and `tmp = 0` are executed, and code flow jumps back to `L1`.
6. Now `'+'` (0x2B) is detected, so code flow proceeds into the `else if` section.

At this point, you have `i==0`, `buffer[0]==4`, `X==4`, `tmp==0`, and `input=='+'` (0x2B). Now for the bug:

1. `X = buffer[i] + X` is executed, or `X = 8`.
2. `buffer[0] = 0` is executed, followed by `tmp = X` (8) and `y = 0`.
3. `output = 0` is executed.
4. `tmp = tmp - power[y]` is executed. Remember `tmp` was just set to 8, and `y==0`. `power[0]==10000`, meaning you're executing `tmp = 8 - 10000`, or `tmp = -9992`.
5. `output++` is executed, setting `output=1`.
6. `-9992 < 10000`, so `goto L3` is skipped.
7. `-9992 < 8`, so you do `output = output + 0x30`, or `output = '1'` and `putchar(output)`.
8. `y++` gets executed, followed by `goto L2`.
9. `output = 0`, followed by `tmp = -9992 - 1000`, or `tmp = -10992`.
10. `output++`, or `output = 1`, followed by `output = output + 0x30` and `putchar(output)`.
11. This sort of logic loops at step 3 until you get to `power[4]`, which is 0.
12. `tmp < 0`, so you don't execute the body of the `if (tmp >= 0)` statement.
13. You jump back to `L1`, and you start things all over again, except you still have a value in `X` (8) and `buffer[0]==0` now. You just have the `'\n'` to process from the `+\n` part, which will just do `buffer[0] = X`, or `buffer[0] = 8`.

As for the fix, one possibility might be to do this:

```
     L3:
        if (tmp >= power[y]) {
            tmp = tmp - power[y];
            output++;
            goto L3;
        }
```

Edit: The [C code](https://pastebin.com/d1ekssXT) you linked [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829568/why-does-my-reverse-polish-notation-output-the-wrong-output/49831765#comment86674579_49829624) did this exact thing. In other words, you just messed up the logic, possibly even thinking that you had a `do-while` loop (condition checked after each run of the loop) when you had a `while` loop (condition checked before each run of the loop).